Where is this verse about pakhandis found?
I read it somewhere " A king shpuld expel pakhandis from his dominion" it was in some purana..kindly find it..

May be you're talking about verse 9.225 of the Manu Smriti:


कितवान् कुशीलवान् क्रूरान् पाषण्डस्थांश्च मानवान् ।
विकर्मस्थान् शौण्डिकांश्च क्षिप्रं निर्वासयेत् पुरात् ॥ २२५ ॥
kitavān kuśīlavān krūrān pāṣaṇḍasthāṃśca mānavān |
vikarmasthān śauṇḍikāṃśca kṣipraṃ nirvāsayet purāt || 225 ||
Gamblers, dancers, cruel men, men belonging to heretical sects, men
addicted to evil deeds, dealers in wine,—these the King shall
instantly banish from his town.—(225)

This verse talks about Pashandas (not Pakhandis),who are men belonging to some heretical sects, and that the king must expel them along few others from his kingdom.
Ganganath Jha's commentary on this verse is as follows:


‘Krūrān’.—Nārāyaṇa and Rāghavānanda read ‘kerān’ and explain it as
‘men of crooked behaviour.’—Nandana reads ‘kailān’ and explains it as
‘men addicted to sporting.’
‘Śauṇḍikān’.—‘Liquor-vendors’ (Nārāyaṇa and Kūlluka);—‘Drunkards’
(Nandana).
This verse is quoted in Vivādaratnākara (p. 315), which adds the
following notes:—‘Kitavān’, fraudulent gamblers;—‘kuśīlavān’, here
stands for those men who are sharp enough to entrap even unwilling
people;—‘kerān’, ‘go-betweens between strange
couples’;—‘pāṣaṇḍasthān’, men belonging to the Kṣapaṇaka and other
heretical sects;—‘Vikarmasthān’, men addicted to entirely forbidden
occupations ‘śauṇḍikān’, men addicted to excessive drinking.
It is quoted in Vīramitrodaya (Rājanīti, p. 153);—and in
Vyavahāra-Bālambhaṭṭī (p. 880).


I read the verse which mentions expel from country..Can you find it for me

When I saw your question I recalled the given verse which talks about expelling from Pura or city/kingdom which is basically the same as expelling from country .. may be some other scriptures have a variant of this verse with country in it @Harsh

Tell me any shlokas which say mlecchas can become krishna devotees

Must be there but at this moment I don't remember any such Sloka @Harsh
